# What would be the most elegant way to implement this without multiple inheritance in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

Basically I have classes of objects whose main function is to act as  tableView Delegate.

I want to add that to some superclass. Of course there is only 1 superclass and I want flexibility. What about if latter I want to add this capability to other classes at will?

Basically these are codes used to handle tables where users can delete or rearrange rows, etc.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSAssert(false, @"Should be called at child View");
    return nil;
}



-(Class) classBookmarked
{
    assert(false);
    return nil;
}


-(void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.delegate.tvDelegated setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (!editing)
    {
        NSArray * newIds = _arManagedObjectArray.convertArrayOfNSManagedObjectToItsDefaultSelector;

        [self varManagedObjectArrayUpdated];
        [BGBookmarkStorer vReportBookmarkStatusToServer:newIds Flag:@"update" withClass:self.classBookmarked];
    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    [self deleteARow:row];

}

-(void)deleteARow:(NSUInteger) row
{
    NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:0];
    [_arManagedObjectArray removeObjectAtIndex:row];
    [self.delegate.tvDelegated deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self varManagedObjectArrayUpdated];
}

-(void) varManagedObjectArrayUpdated
{
    [self.bookmarkStorer vUpdateBookMarkIDwithArray:_arManagedObjectArray];
    [self.delegate vUpdateNumberOfStuffs];

}

-(BGBookmarkStorerForPlacesandCatalog *) bookmarkStorer
{
    assert(false);
    return nil;
}

- (NSArray*) theBookmarkedIDs
{
    return self.bookmarkStorer.bookmarkedIDs;

}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    NSMutableArray *  mutableBusinessBookmarked= _arManagedObjectArray;
    NSManagedObject *bizOrCatToMove = mutableBusinessBookmarked[sourceIndexPath.row];
    [mutableBusinessBookmarked removeObjectAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row];
    [mutableBusinessBookmarked insertObject:bizOrCatToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
    //_arManagedObjectArray=mutableBusinessBookmarked;
    [self varManagedObjectArrayUpdated];
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `I want to add that to some superclass.`

Answer (score 2):

Create a subclass of uitableviewcontroller. Implement all your functions there. Use it as a superclass for all your view controllers.

Comment: superclass is fine. But objective-c doesn't allow multiple inheritance and I want something more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a practical place where you can put that code and reuse in your table view controllers, right?
If so, simply create a category on UITableViewController and put your code there ;-)

Comment: Category is not really flexible. I am thinking of composition. But then the delegate must explicitly call the delegate of the codes I want to repeat.